# What's the difference between Solo and Multiplayer in Elite?

Tags: elite-dangerous

What's the difference between Solo and Online Multiplayer in Elite: Dangerous? If I have a Captain in Solo, will they continue if I play in Multiplayer, or will I start over?

What are the major differences and similarities between these two modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't many differences. You use the same CMDR save file in both solo and open, the background simulation is the same, so the standing of minor factions will be consistent, the only difference is that there are other players in open play, and, obviously, there are none in solo.

Open play can be slightly more dangerous in that regard, since you can run into CMDRs with no regard for the law, and who will usually be more skilled than an NPC pirate.

Comment: Can other players attack and destroy you without your permission?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Yes but it is a crime to do so. So can NPCs.

Comment: That's true, but I favour my chances over NPCs than against people who have played the game a lot longer than me :)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt yes, and some take great pleasure in doing so. Flying round certain busy systems can be a pain in open. Also note that bounties and combat bonds work differently as only the player that did the most damage gets it - this means firefights with lots of other players usually don't get you as much cash.

Comment: @Keith So if the risks are so high, what's the benefit to playing in Open over Solo?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt er, just playing with other people. A lot of people on the forums have been asking for it to be like PvP/PvE in WoW (so you couldn't make progress in Solo and take it to Open - they'd need different saves and only Open progress would be 'legitimate') but David Braben has said that he's dead against that - he wants players to have free choice about whether they play on their own or with others. Personally I find Open really frustrating for any of the more 'grindy' activities (like rare trading) where you can get griefed, but missions are more fun in Open with friends.

Comment: @Keith It's an interesting choice. Given the number of people hacking GTA Online at the moment, I'm kind of surprised that people aren't hacking their Solo games and then taking them into Open and dominating. It's strange that Open is just the presence of other people, as it doesn't sound like you really interact with them outside of just shooting each other? (Ie. There's no "group" missions.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt you can form a wing and go on a mission with them together (for instance to take on a really tough target). I think group missions are in the plan. Solo isn't really offline - you're always playing in the same world, so other players can deplete your trade route and your save appears to always be on their servers. The only difference between Solo and Open is whether other players appear in your current instance, and Open doesn't guarantee that they do (unless you form a wing).

Comment: @Keith Thanks, very informative! I'm guessing that everyone doesn't play on the same system in Open, btw? That seems to be what you're saying. (Although the galaxy might be the same for everyone, it's not like the game universe has thousands and thousands of players in the galaxy together, right? A lobby in GTA Online has limit of 16 or 32 players or something like that.)